# What exactly am I supposed to do when I get a "Object is possibly null" error in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, error-handling, null, compiler-options

In the `compilerOptions` object of my `tsconfig.json` file I have the `strictNullChecks` option set to `true`.

Sometimes, when I use functions like `getElementById("...")` or `querySelector("...")`, I get the following (non-fatal) error:

> TS2531: Object is possibly 'null'

I know **why** I'm getting this error (sometimes the element hasn't loaded yet or it can't be found), but what exactly am I supposed to do when I get this error?

Would it be appropriate to just put the code that used the element(s) inside an `if` condition, like this:

```
let divs: HTMLElement | null = document.getElementById("div");
if(divs !== null) {
  // do stuff with divs...
}
```

Or am I supposed to do something else?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Would it be appropriate to just put the code that used the element(s) inside an if condition

Yes. As you said, sometimes the element isn't there, so you get `null`. Checking for it is appropriate.

If you need to use `getElementById` or `querySelector` in a situation where you **know** the element is there, you might give yourself a helper function that throws rather than returning `null`:

```
function getGuaranteed(id: string): HTMLElement {
    const el = document.getElementById(id);
    if (el == null) {
        throw new Error("Element #" + id + " not found.");
    }
    return el as HTMLElement;
}
```

...and use that in the situations where you know the element will be there.